# Attach a polyline to shape

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, polyline

In a wpf in C# I draw a polyline on a canvas from the edge of a shape (rectangle) by the mouse move. I want to drag and drop then the rectangle with the polyline together as a united shape, In other words I want to attach the polyline to the shape. How could this be done?
Using a canvas is not efficient to this occasion since the length of the polyline is unknown (is determined at runtime of the program) and it is not limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the path object, you can have multiple path figures making one geometry. As for drag and drop, you could use the FillContainsWithDetail() method on the geometry class to calculate the intersection of your figures. If the figures intersect (or one contains the other), you have a valid drop target. On drop, add the figure to you path and you have a composite shape.

Comment: Do geometies accept mouse event handlers? I need to manipulate them with the mouse.

Comment: The Path class inherits from Shape, and it does have mouse events. You should use two path instances, one that is your existing, composite shape, and one that represents the new shape you are wanting to add. On drop, you extract the figure from the new path, and add it to the existing, composite path.